# In MatLab, how can I create a character vector from a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, imread

I am clearly having trouble distinguishing between the different types of vectors and arrays and commands like string, cellstr, char, etc. My code is on another network but basically, I get an error saying the argument in my imread statement must be a character vector. The argument is a 1x30 array of file names and is a cell array because I used iscell command and it came back with a 1. I have tried several combos of the commands listed above and have been reading everything I can but cannot determine how to change the 1x30 cell array to a character vector so the imread statement will work. The file names are read in from a folder (using uigetfile) as 757-01.bmp, 757-02.bmp ... 757-30.bmp. I assume I need to make them '757-01.bmp', '757-02.bmp' ... '757-30.bmp' and possibly into a 30x1 vector vice 1x30? Or perhaps that doesn't matter for the for loop the code will encounter next..? Thank you for any assistance...

```
[imagefiles,file_path]=uigetfile({'*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tif;*.tiff;*.png;*.gif','Image Files (JPEG, BMP, TIFF, PNG and GIF)'},'Select Images','multiselect','on');
imagefiles = cellstr(imagefiles);
imagefiles = sort(imagefiles);
nfiles = length(imagefiles);

r = inputdlg('At what pixel row do you want to start the cropping?        .','Row');
r = str2num(r{l});

c = inputdlg('At what pixel column do you want to start the cropping (Must be > 0)?        .','Column');
c = str2num(c{l});

h = inputdlg('How many pixel rows do you want to include in the crop?        .','Height');
h = str2num(h{l});

w = inputdlg('How many pixel columns do you want to include in the crop?        .','Width');
w = str2num(w{l});

factor = inputdlg('By what real number factor do you want to enlarge the cropped image?        .','Factor');
factor = str2num(factor{l});

outdimR = h * factor;
outdimC = w * factor;

for loop=l:nfiles
    filename = imagefiles(loop);
    [mybmp, map] = imread(filename);
    myimage = ind2rgb(mybmp,map);
    crop = myimage(r:r+h-1, c:c+w-1, :);
    imwrite(crop, sprintf('crop757-%03i.bmp',loop));
end
```

Comment: Can you post your code on how you're using imread? That might be where your error is.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Code is to crop images:

Comment: Try `filename = imagefiles{loop};` (that is, use curly braces instead of parentheses)

Comment: Thank you. It errors out at imread saying File "757-01.bmp" does not exist. In the imagefiles array, the first of 30 values is 757-01.bmp (no quotes) but I don't know if MatLab putting quotes around the file name means its looking for a value with quotes in the array or not.

Comment: Make sure you either addpath or include the directory you are pulling these files from. Otherwise matlab will think they are in your current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your original question:

> In MatLab, how can I create a character vector from a cell array?

You can use cell accessor operands ({}) to get the character string from your cell as @ben-voight pointed out, or alternatively wrap `char()` around your statement (I'd go with Ben's suggestion).

Regarding your follow-on issue:

> It errors out at imread saying File "757-01.bmp" does not exist. In the imagefiles array, the first of 30 values is 757-01.bmp (no quotes) but I don't know if MatLab putting quotes around the file name means its looking for a value with quotes in the array or not.

It sounds like your file is in another directory than the one you are running your code from.

Use [fullfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to create the full filename to use the file's absolute path instead of a relative path (which isn't working here).

Let's say your files in are in the path `~/bpfreefly/images/`.

Then you can change your code like this:

```
imgPath = '~/bpfreefly/images/'
for loop=l:nfiles
    filename = fullfile(imgPath,imagefiles{loop});
    [mybmp, map] = imread(filename);
    myimage = ind2rgb(mybmp,map);
    crop = myimage(r:r+h-1, c:c+w-1, :);
    imwrite(crop, sprintf('crop757-%03i.bmp',loop));
 end
```

By the way, you can get the pathname from `uigetfile`'s second output argument.